# Rotate image with ekko-lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I'm using ekko-lightbox. I'm trying to add Rotate button inside modal to rotate image. My code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(this).ekkoLightbox({
 onShow: function() {
  $('.ekko-lightbox-container').append('<div class="rotate-button"><a href="#" class="pull-right rotate" style="font-size: 18px;padding: 3px 0;"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rotate</a></div>')

  var degrees = 0;
  $('.rotate').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $lightboxphoto = $('.ekko-lightbox');
    degrees += 90;
    $lightboxphoto.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    $lightboxphoto.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  });
},
});
});
```

Modal code:

```
<div id="ekkoLightbox-302" class="ekko-lightbox modal fade in show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="display: block; width: auto; max-width: 280px;">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header" style="display:none">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">&nbsp;</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="ekko-lightbox-container" style="height: 200px;">
      <div class="ekko-lightbox-item fade"></div>
      <div class="ekko-lightbox-item fade in show">
        <img src="https://sparkler-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/fake_data/scrap_1.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="rotate-button"><a href="#" class="pull-right rotate" style="font-size: 18px;padding: 3px 0;"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rotate</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="display:none">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I click on rotate button whole modal is rotated. Like this:

[image]

When I try to select image inside ligthbox in selector to rotate. I get something like this:

[image]

How can fix the Rotate button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

js

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(this).ekkoLightbox({
 onShow: function() {
  $('.ekko-lightbox-container').append('<div class="rotate-button"><a href="#" class="pull-right rotate" style="font-size: 18px;padding: 3px 0;"><i class="fa fa-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></i> Rotate</a></div>')

  var degrees = 0;
  $('.rotate').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $lightboxphoto = $('.ekko-lightbox').children().find('img');
    degrees += 90;
    $lightboxphoto.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
    $lightboxphoto.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)');
  });
},
});
});
```

when rotating image it goes out due to its fixed width,so use **vmin units**.
But they are not supported by IE8([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)).

For IE9 support you need to specify `vm` instead of `vmin`

css

```
  .ekko-lightbox-container img.img-responsive {
    width:90vm; 
    width: 90vmin;
    height:90vm;
    height: 90vmin;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7j38vsy/3/)

Comment: There is no `iframe` inside ekko-lightbox-container in my case.

Comment: K.try this code `var $lightboxphoto=$('.ekko-lightbox').children().find('img');`

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/n7j38vsy/3/ .when rotating image it goes out due to its fixed width,in this i changed image width according to popup width

Comment: Where exactly in code are you changing image width?